# How can change lockscreen wallpaper in android with code?

Tags: android

**i can change home screen wallpaper but i can not change lock screen wallpaper,**

```
                DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                // get the height and width of screen
                int height = metrics.heightPixels;
                int width = metrics.widthPixels;

                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                        .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);


                wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
```

Answer (score 7):

As of the latest Android API 24 it is possible to update the `Lockscreen` wallpaper by using the `WallpaperManager` and providing the `FLAG_LOCK` flag.

```
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK)
```

Comment: it's work me but not in Marshmallow phone

Comment: @RobbyPatel as mentioned this was added in API 24 (so it is not available in android versions prior to API 24) and there will never come support

Comment: but some Samsung phone has available Lock Screen Wallpaper how it works?

Comment: As samsung is modifying the SystemUI they can do whatever they want. But they do not offer an API via the android SDK to allow you to change that

Comment: my device version is 24, it is not working

Comment: Which device do you use @theLazyFinder Some OEMs do not allow these APIs and you are sadly out of luck with these devices

Comment: I am using Redmi note 4

Comment: This Code is not working on Redmi Note 5 Pro, API 27. Any one has any idea why it is not working or any way to check if the device is supported apart from API level?

Comment: @AvineetGupta This is a limitation of MIUI. Please see https://in.c.mi.com/thread-1252992-1-0.html