# Is there any way of changing LockScreen Wallpaper/photo in Android programmatically

Tags: java, android, widget, lockscreen, wallpaper

I want to change the lockscreen wallpaper of Android. I was able to change home screen wallpaper through `WallpaperManager.setResource`

But I am unable to set LockScreen Wallpaper

Also is there any way to change it over time automatically?

Comment: add the code snippet that you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frist Create Bitmap source from drawable Resource

Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getViewContext().getResources(),
R.drawable.wall);

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager =WallpaperManager.getInstance(getViewContext());
        try {
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(icon, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest Android API 24 it is possible to update the Lockscreen wallpaper by using the WallpaperManager and providing the FLAG_LOCK flag.

wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK)

check this question for more details.

[How can change lockscreen wallpaper in android with code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256540/how-can-change-lockscreen-wallpaper-in-android-with-code)