# wallpaper function in Xamarin.Android. How does is work and how to use it?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bitmap, wallpaper

in UWP apps i can use this code to set a `StorageFile` as a device Wallpaper for both Desktop and Lockscreen:

```
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ApplyWallpaper(StorageFile storageFile)
{
   await UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(storageFile);
   await UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync(storageFile);
}
```

looking for Xamarin.Android I found the WallpaperManager but I dont really how to use it exactly.

```
static WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager;
public static void ApplyToDesktop(Bitmap bitmap)
{
   myWallpaperManager.SetBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

can you tell me the equivalent of the UWP code for the Xamarin.Android?

Comment: SetBitmap seems pretty straightforward.  What don't you understand about using it?

Comment: how do i do it on the Lockscreen ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256540/how-can-change-lockscreen-wallpaper-in-android-with-code

Answer (score 1):

First, add permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

Then, set the wallpaper, `sample` here is the name of image in the `Drawable` folder:

```
public void setWallpaper() {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources,Resource.Drawable.sample);

    WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.GetInstance(ApplicationContext);

    manager.SetBitmap(bitmap);
    //or
    manager.SetBitmap(bitmap, null, true, WallpaperManagerFlags.Lock);

}
```

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/WallPaper-Android) and you can check it.